# PHP SimpleXML modifies line break characters in CDATA elements

Tags: php, xml, cdata

I am using PHP version 5.3.9. I am running into problems using SimpleXML because it is changing the line ending characters in CDATA sections when parsing xml files.

For example:

```
$string = "<value><![CDATA[hello\r\nworld]]></value>";

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
var_dump((string)$xml);

var_dump("hello\r\nworld");
```

Outputs:

```
string(11) "hello world"
string(12) "hello world"
```

Even without looking at the hex values you can immediately see that the SimpleXML parsed version is changing the newline from a windows "\r\n" newline into a unix "\n" newline from the string lengths. This is a problem because I would like to store `serialize()`ed objects in my XML file, but `serialize()` stores the exact length of any strings it serializes, including the newline characters. When I try to `unserialize()` the strings after reading in the XML the string length is no longer correct because of the changed line ending and it fails to properly unserialize. It is possible to work around this by making sure I sanitize every input string to replace "\r\n" with "\n" but this doesn't seem like it's something I should need to do.

I was under the impression that XML parsers were not supposed to parse the contents of CDATA elements in any way. Am I misunderstanding how CDATA sections are specified, am I misusing SimpleXML somehow, or is this a bug in SimpleXML?

Comment: Almost 9 years later, and this question goes unanswered.  Why does the PHP XML parser manipulate the data in `<![CDATA[...\r\n...]]>` and throw away the `\r`?  CDATA should mean "don't change this data in any way".  Why does the PHP XML parser change it?  And it's not a matter of using ' versus " when declaring the string.  If you read in your XML from an external source (file, function param, etc.), then you're not working with static strings.  The PHP XML parser has a bug, and no one has fixed it for years.

Comment: I also "think" the OP actually had the literal 0x0D and 0x0A in the data, and used \r\n to represent those characters when asking the question.  I do not think the OP had the 4 characters `\r\n` in the `CDATA` element.  I'm experiencing the same issue.  My 0x0D is discarded in the `CDATA` element when calling `simplexml_load_string()`.

Answer (score -2):

I didn't get your point.

but just notice that you had use double quotes.

in my variant:

```
$string = '<value><![CDATA[hello\r\nworld]]></value>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
var_dump($xml->__toString());
var_dump((string)$xml);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
var_dump($xml->__toString());

var_dump('hello\r\nworld');
```

outputs

```
string(14) "hello\r\nworld"
string(14) "hello\r\nworld"
string(14) "hello\r\nworld"
string(14) "hello\r\nworld"
```

but what is your expectation? just tell us what it should be?

Comment: I'm not sure how familiar you are with PHP, but in PHP you must [use double quotes in order to use escape characters](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double). In my question I'm asking about SimpleXML changing the escaped \r (carriage return) and \n (linefeed) characters from the two characters into a single \n character. In your example your strings have the literal four characters "\r\n" which is completely different.

Comment: sorry, but you are little bit wrong about where the issue IS. :-) the issue is THE ORIGINAL STRING WITH DATA. so I didn't change something with simple XML. I just prepared source string more accurately. that mean your issue is cased not by weird SimpleXML behavior, but wrong source data string you send to xml.

Comment: What exactly is "wrong" with my original source string? Are linefeed and carriage return characters somehow not valid in XML? You're completely ignoring the question if you say "just change your input string" unless you have a good reason why the input string is invalid XML.

Comment: do `var_dump($string);` as second line in your code, just after $string initialization in your variant and in my, you will see what do I mean by wrong data source.

Comment: I have done that. There is nothing wrong with the data source. If you have a point state it clearly, don't say "try this and see".

Comment: you wrote in your question `after reading in the XML the string length is no longer correct`, could you tell me what `correct length` do you expect?

Comment: I thought it was clear enough from the example I wrote, but I am expecting the string length after XML parsing to be the same as before XML parsing. From the example output you can see that the original string is 12 characters long, while the XML parsed string is 11 characters long (because the line break is reduced from a linebreak character and a carriage return character into just a single linebreak character by the XML parsing).

Comment: sorry, but from your example it is not clear. you did not do: `var_dump($string)` against `var_dump($xml->toString())`. If you do `var_dump($string)` once before any xml transformation you would see that xml returns exact the same string value as it was in original `$string` variable

Comment: or you mean `$string = '<value><![CDATA[hello\r\nworld]]></value>';
var_dump($string);` outputs `string(41) "<value><![CDATA[hello\r\nworld]]></value>"` and correct string length is 41??

Comment: I do not do `var_dump($string)` in my example because it has the extra "<![CDATA[" text that only confuses the issue, but I have output that and I can assure you that you are wrong, the original $string has the newline and carriage return preserved while the xml output does not. Also if you are still using single quotes you are doing it completely wrong. My example does not work with single quotes, for reasons I have already explained.

Comment: I just asked what is your `correct length`? 14? 12? 41?

Comment: The relevant string here is the "hello\r\nworld". It has a string length of 12: 5 characters for "hello", 1 carriage return character, 1 newline character, 5 characters for "world". When put into an xml CDATA element the output should be exactly what is between <![CDATA[ and ]]>, which as you can see in my example is those 12 characters. Instead, as you can see in the example output, the xml output of the relevant string has 11 characters: 5 for "hello", 1 for a newline character, and 5 for "world".